# Graphics with dataframe

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I have a table with export of every EU country:

```
country 2001  2002  2003  .....
france  12023 54554 251515 ....
.....
```

I would like to do a plot with the value of every years for 4 country (e.g. Germany, Italy, France, Netherlands). It's a dataframe I have tried with those commands:

```
y<-ts(EXEU)
y
plot(y[5,],type="o")
```

But when I use `ts` I lose all the name of the countries and I have on the x-axis frequency not every years. It's possible to do the same without use `ts()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#EXEU is your dataframe
EXEU<-melt(EXEU,id='country',variable.name='YEAR',value.name='VALUE')
ggplot(EXEU,aes(YEAR,VALUE,group=country, color=country))+geom_line()
```

[image: Picture example]